# sympyでsolveを2回実行すると、TypeErrorがでます。

Tags: python, sympy

原因を教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。

```
from sympy import *
A=Symbol('A',real=True,positive=True)
A=solve(Eq(1,A**2),A)
print("# 1",A)
A=solve(Eq(1,A**2),A)
print("# 2",A)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "C:/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 5, in <module>
#     A=solve(Eq(1,A**2),A)
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
# # 1 [1]
```

1回だと、うまくいきます。

```
from sympy import *
A=Symbol('A',real=True,positive=True)
A=solve(Eq(1,A**2),A)
print("# 1",A)
# 1 [1]
```

(20220819)
変数名を変更

```
from sympy import *
A=Symbol('A',real=True,positive=True)
B=Symbol('B',real=True,positive=True)
A=solve(Eq(1,A**2),A)
print("# 1",A)
B=solve(Eq(1,B**2),B)
print("# 2",B)
# 1 [1]
# 2 [1]
```

Symbolを2回

```
from sympy import *
A=Symbol('A',real=True,positive=True)
A=solve(Eq(1,A**2),A)
print("# 1",A)
A=Symbol('A',real=True,positive=True)
A=solve(Eq(1,A**2),A)
print("# 2",A)
# 1 [1]
# 2 [1]
```

printを続けて

```
from sympy import *
A=Symbol('A',real=True,positive=True)
print("# 1",solve(Eq(1,A**2),A))
print("# 2",solve(Eq(1,A**2),A))
# 1 [1]
# 2 [1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1行目の`A=Symbol('A',real=True,positive=True)`を実行した後のAのタイプは`<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>`です。※print(type(A))で確認しました。
2行目の`A=solve(Eq(1,A**2),A)`を実行した後のAのタイプは`<class 'list'>`です。

2回目の`A=solve(Eq(1,A**2),A)`でエラーになるのは`<class 'list'>`である`A`に対して演算を行っているからだと思います。

以下のように演算結果の変数名をAではないものに変えれば、2回目も同じ結果になると思います。

```py
from sympy import *
A=Symbol('A',real=True,positive=True)
ans=solve(Eq(1,A**2),A)
print("# 1",ans)
ans=solve(Eq(1,A**2),A)
print("# 2",ans)
```